# Calculate one static input field and three dynamically created input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex problem in jQuery. I want to calculate the one static input field and three dynamically calculated field's value in jQuery.

Here is the input method created in HTML

```
 <input type="text" required name="prodeyo_3[]" class="form-control"/>
 <input type="text" id="somaponyJer" required name="somapony_jer[]"/>
```

I just want to get the value of `id=somaponyJer` . Then I want to get the values of dynamically created input by jQuery.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".addrowMushok18").click(function () {

            var n = ($('.row_append tr').length - 0) + 1;


            var tr = '<tr>\
                        <td>' + n + '</td>\
                        <td><input type="date" required name="transection_date[]" class="form-control"></td>\
                        <td><input type="text" required name="transection_details[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
                        <td><input type="text" required name="purchase_sales_statement[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
                        <td><input type="date" required name="purchase_sales_date[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
                        <td><input type="text" required id="newTreasuryDeposit" name="treasury_deposit[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
                        <td><input type="text" required id="newReyat" name="reyat_2[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
                        <td><input type="text" required id="newProdeyo" name="prodeyo_3[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
                        <td><input type="text" required id="newSomaponyJer" required name="somapony_jer[]" class="form-control" value/></td>\
                        <td><input type="text" required name="remarks[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
                        <td align="center"><span class="remove_row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Delete!" ></i></span></td>\
                    </tr>';

          $(".row_append").append(tr);
         }); 
});
```

From this dynamically created input fileds, I want to get the values of `id="newTreasuryDeposit" , id="newReyat" id="newSomaponyJer"`

and  then calculate them and insert into `id="newSomaponyJer"` which is created by JQuery.

Please help.

Comment: As long as your calculate function is going to run after the dynamic fields are appended to the current `DOM` they can be fetched easily. As they are in the `.row_append`, simply do a `find` like:  `$('.row_append').find('#newTreasuryDeposit').val()`,`$('.row_append').find('#newReyat').val()`,`$('.row_append').find('#newSomaponyJer').val()` to get the individual value and then do your calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Note that I have added buttons and table that were missing in the html that you have posted, so change it according to your html. And for the *caluclate* part, I have just added inserted numbers together, change that according to your needs as well.

Click `add` button to generate that `tr`, fill fields with the mentioned ids, click `calculate` button. Result will be shown in the filed with id = `newSomaponyJer`.

```js
function calculateValue() {
  const $sj = document.querySelector('#somaponyJer');
  const $ntd = document.querySelector('#newTreasuryDeposit');
  const $nr = document.querySelector('#newReyat');
  const $nsj = document.querySelector('#newSomaponyJer');

  //do some calculation e.g. sum them
  const result = Number($sj.value) + Number($ntd.value) + Number($nr.value);
  $nsj.value = result;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".addrowMushok18").click(function () {
    var n = ($('.row_append tr').length - 0) + 1;
      var tr = '<tr>\
        <td>' + n + '</td>\
        <td><input type="date" required name="transection_date[]" class="form-control"></td>\
        <td><input type="text" required name="transection_details[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" required name="purchase_sales_statement[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
        <td><input type="date" required name="purchase_sales_date[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" required id="newTreasuryDeposit" name="treasury_deposit[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" required id="newReyat" name="reyat_2[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" required id="newProdeyo" name="prodeyo_3[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
        <td><input type="text" required id="newSomaponyJer" required name="somapony_jer[]" class="form-control" value/></td>\
        <td><input type="text" required name="remarks[]" class="form-control" /></td>\
        <td align="center"><span class="remove_row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Delete!" ></i></span></td>\
      </tr>';
    $(".row_append").append(tr);
  });

  $('.calculate').click(calculateValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" required name="prodeyo_3[]" class="form-control"/>
<input type="text" id="somaponyJer" required name="somapony_jer[]"/>
<button class="addrowMushok18">add</button>
<button class="calculate">calculate</button>
<table>
  <tr class="row_append"></tr>
<table>
```